# R: how to pass a list of plots from a function and access the contents?

Tags: r, list, plot, ggplot2

I am creating some plots in a function and then I pass them to the regular code.  There are no error messages but when I run the code, the code is not receiving the plot - the plots do not appear after returning from the function.

This is my code.  Please let me know what I am doing wrong so it can work.
Thanks

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
require(grid)

create_plots <- function(selection)  {  
    temp_plot <- list()

    if(selection == 1) 
    {
        temp_plot[[1]] <- hist(mtcars$mpg, 
                               main="my histogram",
                               xlab="xlabel", 
                               ylab="ylabel")
        return(temp_plot)
    }

    if(selection == 2) 
    {
        temp_plot[[1]] <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mtcars$mpg)) +
                                 geom_histogram(binwidth=0.10, colour="black", fill="white") +
                                 ggtitle ("frequency!!") + 
                                 labs(x=mpg, y="frequency")
        return(temp_plot)
    }

    if(selection == 3) 
    {
       temp_plot[[1]] <- barplot(mtcars$mpg, 
                                 main="my barplot",
                                 xlab="xlabel", 
                                 ylab="ylabel")
       return(temp_plot)
    }

}

plot_list2 <- list()
plot_list3 <- list()

plot_list2[[1]]<-create_plots(1) #ok
plot(plot_list2[[1]][[1]])  # ok
plot_list2[[2]]<-create_plots(2) #ok
plot(plot_list2[[2]][[1]]) #ok
plot_list2[[3]]<-create_plots(3) #ok
plot(plot_list2[[3]][[1]]) #prints some strange plot not my barplot, why?

plot_list3<-create_plots(1) #ok
plot(plot_list3[[1]]) #ok
plot_list3<-create_plots(2)
plot(plot_list3[[2]]) #subscript out of bounds error for a list of TWO items???
plot_list3<-create_plots(3)  #ok
plot(plot_list3[[3]]) #subscript out of bounds error for a list of TWO items???
```

Comment: restart the session...it plots when you call the function create_plot()

Comment: If you assign the results of `hist`, you capture its results, not its side effect (i.e. plotting). To plot after the fact, you need to call `plot`, e.g. `plot(plot_list2[[1]][[1]])` or `plot(plot_list3[[1]])`.

Comment: Hi Alistaire.  I applied your suggestions and some plots print but now one plot does not print and others are out of bounds for just 2 items which is odd.  Does anyone know why this is happening? I have a 20 rows of data and want to call that function for each row and save the data in a list, then loop through the list to print to a pdf and these list errors are preventing me from doing that.  This is confusing :(

Comment: Seems like one of the issues is how `barplot()` works.  Maybe ask a question specific to `barplot`?  Some of the other issues may be because of working with ggplot2 vs base plotting.  In base you can `plot` the results, but that won't necessarily work with a ggplot2 object.

Comment: do you know why the list would state subscripts out of bounds with only 2 items?

Comment: It looks like your function always returns a `list` with a single plot in it. Why not just return the plot itself? As for your error, when you do, e.g., `plot_list3<-create_plots(2)` you are completely overwriting `plot_list3` with the return of `create_plots(2)` - a list with one element. So of course when you do `plot(plot_list3[[2]])` the 2 is out of bounds. You could instead do `plot_list3 <- c(plot_list3, create_plots(2))` to *append* the new plot list to your existing list.

Comment: But maybe better would be modify your function to return a the plot instead of the list of the plot and assign to the list element, `plot_list3[[2]] <- modified_create_plots(2)`